# Как проверить видимый ли элемент или нет

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть элемент изначально скрытый

```
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
```

При ховере он стает видимым

Мне нужно, после того как страничка загрузилась, узнать видим он или нет.
Нужно для того, чтобы если при загрузке я заховерю, то после загрузки выполнился скрипт.

Проблема в том что

```
console.log($('.selector').css('visibility'));
```

возвращает hidden хотя я при загрузке заховерил и по логике елемент видимый.
Ищу еще варианты получение состояния элемента.

Comment: где ты выполняешь этот код? ты уверен, что в момент его выполнения действительно курсор был над нужным элементом?

Comment: Ну в момент загрузки я сделал ховер и вижу скрытый элемент логично что он уже появился.

Comment: что ты понимаешь под моментом загрузки? пересмотри мой вопрос в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: момент как страничка еще рендерится. код выполняется на сайте. код выполняется на документ реди

Comment: если _страничка еще рендерится_ - то как ты можешь навести на какой-то элемент?

Comment: ну в процессе рендера появляются елементы и как только я вижу елемент я делаю ховер

Comment: Отсюда вопрос: почему ты думаешь, что когда ты делаешь hover твой код еще не отработал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не рассматриваешь как вариант не в стилях `visibility: visible;` при ховере делать, а просто добавлять элементу класс, в котором как раз таки и будет `visibility: visible;`. И проверять на наличие класса? `console.log($('.selector').hasClass('class'));`. То есть при ховере будешь добавлять нужный класс этому элементу.